# Sonarqube plugin 3.5 for java

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, ibm-rad, sonarlint-eclipse

Hi I am trying to analyse Java code with Sonarqube plugin version 3.5 with RAD 9.1.1 ( Eclipse 4.2). I am following steps from http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse . But while configuring when I right click on project and try to select SonarQube project it is showing "No Project Found ".
if any new document available please refer. 
I want to analyse code directly from RAD .

Comment: Why not try to use SonarLint : http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/  ?

Comment: organisation has sonarQube and it do  not allow me to download or install sonarLint.